# Rotating a diagrammatic table in Microsoft Excel such that it changes the vertical scale to the horizontal scale and vice versa for small section

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Trying to rotate a diagrammatic table in Microsoft Excel such that it changes the vertical scale to the horizontal scale and vice versa for a section.

e.g., A particular row has a height of 40.1 but if I try to change a column width to match this for the same table turned on its side it is not the same.

Comment: Did you use the paste transform to rotate the table?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is easily overcome by changing your view from "Normal" to "Page Layout."

You do this by finding the `VIEW` tab of the Ribbon Menu and near the left edge clicking on `Page Layout`.

Go there when done formatting and select `Normal` to return to what almost everyone on Earth is used to.

The reason you need the Page Layout view is that in it, Excel measures the width and height of a cell using the same measuring tool. So, you can easily make the dimensions match in your needed manner.

In the Normal view, Excel measures width using the number of characters in whatever font you have selected. So 8.43 means 8.43 of your font's characters. Which characters? All of them averaged out? The "M"? The "i"? Now change fonts... See what a bizarre world that is?

And then it measures height in standard "points" at 72 points per inch. Straightforward, right? Nah. 72 points should give an inch high space (don't even begin to think about how that space is actually spun out for various font features!) so if you used borders to make a box, it should be one inch from bottom border to top, right? Nope.

And there is utterly no relationship to be learned between this kind of height and width measuring. Different measuring tools, and then those tools kind of vary about and around and about...

In Page Layout view, height and width are measured the same way with the same units. My setting is inches, yours might be centimeters or points, Excel has several options. But since each direction is measured the same way with the same units, you can size a cell to be square, or whatever precise thing you need.

It's still "only so accurate" because Excel still doesn't do it too exactly, but the wrongnesses are tiny, not of any concern usually. Also, after shifting back to Normal view, changing heights or widths puts you back into the same cruddy wagon you were in to start with so keep it in mind. Obviously? Well, ever paste something and Excel resized the width? Yeah, changing a width... not something you were forgetful enough to do, but Excel had your back and did the mistake for you... Moved a column into the region... ahh... turns out you can't check the region's width, copy it to the clipboard, then size the column by pasting the copied value in because even though it's literally the same, a pasted or typed value is not in fact the same as the "converted" value Excel showed you.

I sometimes need squares. My main use of Page Layout view. I set it up so I can see things as desired while building the content of the spreadsheet, then go back to it at the end to dress the region of squares back up. You'll find something along those lines that works for you.

It's not perfect, but darn close for most people's vision. And making squares isn't my main reason for using Excel, even when including such constructs in the body of the spreadsheet. So I have no complaints, just some huffing about at the obnoxiousness of it all. Try it and I think it's likely you'll fall in the same category.